# creating uiview programmatically?

Tags: ios, uiview

Creating a view with following code.

```
  - (void)loadView {

paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 430)];
[paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
self.view = paintView;
[paintView release];
```

But my problem is whole screen fills with yellow color, but I want with specified frame.
I am creating this view in a view based application.. Am i doing something wrong, Overridind the original view?

Comment: but I am starting from 50 in y axis.

Comment: why you are assigning paintView to self.view 
self.view =paintView;

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it in following way.

```
  - (void)loadView {
    /// make a empty view to self.view 
    /// after calling [super loadView], self.view won't be nil anymore. 
    [super loadView]; 

    paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 430)];
    [paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:paintView];
    [paintView release];
  };
```

Comment: Your custom implementation of this method should not call super. If you want to perform any additional initialization of your views, do so in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @Alexey, Maybe in your case, you don't need to implement the custom `loadView`. And this answer is some kind old. At iOS SDK 4/5, this answer is right. The [super loadView] will generate a empty view to `self.view`. And under iOS 7 now, I don't know that works or not.

Comment: There is a typo in the code and SO won't let me edit the answer. The method is "addSubview" not "addSubView".

Comment: Thank you very much. I had modify the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,35)];
newView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
UITextView *mytext = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 0.0, 100.0, 28.0)];
mytext.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
mytext.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
mytext.editable = NO;
mytext.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
mytext.text = @"Mytext";
mytext.scrollEnabled=NO;
[mytext release];
[newView addSubview:mytext];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `self.view =paintView;`
by

```
[self.view addSubview: paintView];
```

Comment: u have missed [super loadView] in ur loadview, add this then ur app won't crashes.

Comment: You should change your answer to include the correct solution from the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I am Going change Line No 3 in LoadView Method , you should add the subView in main View instead on assiging it Directly.

```
[self.view addSubview:paintview];
```